# Align SVG to the center of a div in sass

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm having trouble aligning my SVGs to the center of the circle, how should I go about doing it?

I've tried using imgs in place of the svgs but the quality suffers greatly. Also, I've tried the answers here on stack overflow and tried using the solutions but to no avail.

I have this:
[image]

Want this:
[image]

HTML

```
<div class="topics-container">
 <div class="row1">
        <div class="topic">
            <div class="icon-cybersecurity"><svg>BLAHBLAHBLAH</svg></div>
            <div class="topic-name">Cybersecurity and Social Engineering</div>
        </div>

        <div class="topic">
            <div class="icon-vr"><svg>BLAHBLAHBLAH</svg></div>
            <div class="topic-name">Virtual Reality</div>
        </div>
        .
        .
        .

 </div>
 <div class="row2"> 
        <div class="topic">
        .
        .
        .
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
 </div>
</div>
```

SASS:

```
.row1
  background: blue
  +display(flex)
  +align-items(center)


.row2
  background: red
  +display(flex)
  +align-items(center)

.topic
  display: block
  margin: auto

  [class^="icon-"]
  +size(100px)
  background: green
  border-radius: 50%
```

Comment: We need the compiled CSS but off-hand, I'd say you need to extend the flex properties to the icon divs...as they are not inherited.

Comment: Use http://fontastic.me/ to create font with svg icon set, and use it in your web projects. Morever, you can also export icons from Illustrator - http://fontastic.me/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your help, I figured out a solution, the svg file was not aligned to the center, so I had to do that in illustrator.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a new illustrator file, 100px x 100px
2. Dragged the svg into the white space
3. Pressed transform, set the x and y to 50px

[image: Pressed transform, set the x and y to 50px]
 4. Saved as .svg

[image]

5. Connected the .svg to the code
6. Repeat, Voila

Results:
[image]

Code I used:
SASS:

```
.row1
  +display(flex)
  +align-items(center)

.row2
  padding-top: 150px
  +display(flex)
  +align-items(center)
  padding-bottom: 100px


.topic
  display: block
  margin: auto
  background: white

  [class^="icon-"]
  +size(150px)
  border-radius: 50%

.topic-name
  font-size: 20px
  font-style: bold
  text-align: center
```

HTML: (same as question)

```
<div class="topics-container">
 <div class="row1">
        <div class="topic">
            <div class="icon-cybersecurity"><svg>BLAHBLAHBLAH</svg></div>
            <div class="topic-name">Cybersecurity and Social Engineering</div>
        </div>

        <div class="topic">
            <div class="icon-vr"><svg>BLAHBLAHBLAH</svg></div>
            <div class="topic-name">Virtual Reality</div>
        </div>
        .
        .
        .

 </div>
 <div class="row2"> 
        <div class="topic">
        .
        .
        .
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
 </div>
</div>
```

My SVG File:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M68.9,25c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-0.5,0.1-0.8,0.5-0.8,1c0,1.9-0.9,3-2.5,4s-4,1.9-6.4,2.9s-4.9,2.3-6.8,4.4c-1.8,1.9-3,4.5-3.2,8
    c-1.8-0.1-2.9-0.7-4.1-1.4c-1.5-0.8-3.2-1.7-6-1.7c-1.7,0-3.3,1-4.9,2.5s-3.1,3.5-4.4,5.9C27,55.5,25,61.5,25,66.8
    c0,2.2,0.5,4.2,1.6,5.7c1,1.5,2.6,2.5,4.4,2.5c4.8,0,8.3-2.5,11.2-4.8s5.2-4.4,7.8-4.4s4.8,2,7.8,4.4C60.7,72.5,64.2,75,69,75
    c1.8,0,3.4-1,4.4-2.5c1-1.5,1.6-3.5,1.6-5.7c0-5.4-2-11.3-4.7-16.1c-1.3-2.4-2.8-4.4-4.4-5.9s-3.2-2.5-4.9-2.5c-2.8,0-4.5,0.9-6,1.7
    c-1.2,0.6-2.2,1.2-3.9,1.3c0.2-3,1.2-5,2.6-6.6c1.6-1.7,3.8-2.9,6.2-3.9c2.3-1,4.7-1.8,6.7-3.1s3.4-3.1,3.4-5.8c0-0.6-0.4-1-1-1.1
    C69,25,68.9,25,68.9,25z M39,44.4c2.4,0,3.6,0.6,5,1.4s3.2,1.7,6,1.7c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3,0c0,0,0,0,0,0c2.6-0.1,4.3-0.9,5.7-1.7
    c1.5-0.8,2.6-1.4,5-1.4c0.9,0,2.2,0.6,3.5,1.9c1.4,1.3,2.8,3.2,4,5.4c2.5,4.5,4.4,10.2,4.4,15c0,1.9-0.5,3.5-1.2,4.5
    C71.1,72.4,70.2,73,69,73c-4.2,0-7.2-2.1-10-4.4c-2.8-2.3-5.5-4.8-9-4.8s-6.2,2.5-9,4.8S35.2,73,31,73c-1.2,0-2.1-0.5-2.8-1.6
    c-0.7-1.1-1.2-2.7-1.2-4.5c0-4.8,1.9-10.6,4.4-15c1.3-2.2,2.7-4.1,4-5.4C36.8,45,38.1,44.4,39,44.4z M62,51.5c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2
    s0.9,2,2,2s2-0.9,2-2S63.1,51.5,62,51.5z M37,52.6v3.1h-3v3.1h3v3.1h3v-3.1h3v-3.1h-3v-3.1H37z M58,55.6c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2s0.9,2,2,2
    s2-0.9,2-2S59.1,55.6,58,55.6z M66,55.6c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2s0.9,2,2,2s2-0.9,2-2S67.1,55.6,66,55.6z M62,59.7c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2
    c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2s2-0.9,2-2C64,60.6,63.1,59.7,62,59.7z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd SASS syntax which may be the source of your issues but you need to extend the flex properties to the icon divs...as they are not inherited.

In raw CSS

```css
.icon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #0f0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.topic {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="topic">
    <div class="icon">
      <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/50/50" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="name">Bill Murray</div>
  </div>
  <div class="topic">
    <div class="icon">
      <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/50/50" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="name">Bill Murray</div>
  </div>
  <div class="topic">
    <div class="icon">
      <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/50/50" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="name">Bill Murray</div>
  </div>
</div>
```